# Selecting vs selecting for

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammaticality-in-context, prepositional-phrases

- See in this sense refers to **selecting for** variants that do reproductively useful things.

What does **for** function here in  this sentence.

As far as i am concerned, we can use **for** when the word “select” comes in a passive form as following:

> - the players were selected **for** their outstanding performance.

- What is the reason for including **for** after selecting In the first mentioned sentence above?

Comment: Would you provide a link to the source of this? Perhaps, I can select this question **for** the further investigation!

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.psychologytoday.com/ca/blog/pop-psych/201407/practice-makes-better-not-necessarily-much-better%3famp @Cardinal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Selecting variants* means that you only pick variants.

> I am selecting variants. (I will only choose variants.)

*Selecting* ***for*** *variants* means that you pick things that aren't necessarily variants themselves, but which will lead to variants.

> I am selecting for variants. (I will choose anything that will get me closer to having a variant in the end.)

---

In this case, although its application is a bit unusual, it uses the following sense of the word [*for*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for):

> **1 a** —used as a function word to indicate purpose
>   // a grant *for* studying medicine

In other examples:

> I am looking *for* red jellybeans.
>   I am listening *for* traffic.
>   → My looking and listening is being used as a means to discover red jellybeans and traffic.
>
> I am selecting *for* variants.
>   → My selection process is being used as a means to discover variants.

Answer (score 1):

The full source sentence is:

> This captures nicely some of the logic of evolutionary theory – a piece that many people seem to not appreciate – namely that evolution cannot “see” what you feel; it can only “see” what organisms do (seeing in this sense refers to selecting for variants that do reproductively useful things).

In the domain of evolutionary theory, traits or variants are often said to be 'selected for" or "selected against". A variant is said to be selected for if organisms with that variant leave more offspring, so that they are better represented in the next generation. It is also common to write of "selection for X" where X is some trait subject to natural selection. The "for" is commonly used, because it is meaningless in this theory to speak of selection without indicting what is begin affected, positively or negatively by the selection, and because such selection changes frequencies in a population, rather than making absolute choices from a list or menu.

Here it seems that the model of evolutionary theory is being used as a metaphor, but the characteristic terminology of that field is being used.